# Smarty multiple random numbers list

Tags: php, smarty, random

is there any smart way to post random numbers (e.g. 1-4) in a list by using the smarty tpl-engine?

standart list sorted 1-5:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my solution (PHP):

```
<ul>
{foreach from=randomNumbers}
<li>{smarty.randomNumbers}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

modified list sorted 1-5 (random):

```
<ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I've really tested nearly everything, but I do only need a smart & small solution for this :-)

**Kind Regards,
Heinrich**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rand() function from php in smarty. Pass the parameter as the number of times you run the loop and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could do something really dirty like this:</strike>

```
<ul>
  {foreach from=0|range:4|@array_rand:5 item=i}
    {assign var=i value=$i+1}
    <li>{$i}</li>
  {/foreach}
</ul>
```

**Edit**

As you said `array_rand()` no longer shuffles results. You can't really use `shuffle()` easily because it does not return the shuffled array - you could do something like this though:

```
//somewhere in an included PHP file
function shuffle_array($array){ 
   shuffle($array);
   return $array;   
}

{*template *}
<ul>
  {foreach from=1|range:5|@shuffle_array item=i}
    <li>{$i}</li>
  {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: @Heinrich: what output are you getting?

Comment: by using your code snippet, I get a clean numeric output: 1,2,3,4,5, not a randome one like 5,4,2,1,3 or 4,1,2,3,5 etc. :-/

Comment: @Heinrich: weird. it works for me. i guess you've tried everything like clearing templates_c/

Comment: yes, but I still get 1,2,3,4,5 :-(, do I need a specific smarty.plugin to run your code-snippet correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems to be a PHP-Problem. Since the last PHP versions, array_rand isn't random any more. I've tried to add something like this

```
    |shuffle

or

    shuffle();
```

to tom's smarty-code,

but without success >_<

...

Comment: unfortunately that won't work because shuffle modifies the passed array and returns a bool